Installing Pytorch on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
I am installing Pytorch on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2.
Here is what I have tried:
(from pytorch website https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ )
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/pytorch $ pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Tried other methods but getting same error.

PyTorch only provides pip packages for Arm 64bit (aarch64) so you’ll need to install a 64 bit version of the OS on your Raspberry Pi
Ref - https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/realtime_rpi.html#installing-pytorch-and-opencv
